# How to use MySql Procedure to display result based on some input filters ignoring other filters if not entered on the front end by user?

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I would like to use procedure on button click of more detailed search wherein if I enter all the input value then it is is displaying appropriate result. But, I would like to make my procedure more dynamic such that If I did not enter any Title then it will display all the records based on the other filters including the equivalent values for game title. Also, if the platform or completeness or any other value is missing then also it should return the query result for all possible filter. So, how can I achieve that in MySql?

I want to learn below procedure call

```
call sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions('S','Extreme Sports','3',' ',' ' ,'Good','2000-11-07','2011-06-15',12,67);
```

or

```
call sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions('S',' ','3',NULL,' ','Good','2000-11-07','2011-06-15',12,67);
```

Below is the Procedure:

```
USE `videogame_collection_1`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_search_Records_on_all_conditions` (IN Game_Name_ip     VARCHAR(100),IN Genre_ip ENUM('Controllers', 'Extreme Sports', 'Action &     Adventure', 'Racing', 'RPG', 'Baseball', 'Sports', 'Systems', 'Puzzle',     'Fighting', 'Strategy', 'FPS', 'Wrestling', 'Accessories', 'Soccer', 'Other',     'Football', 'Party', 'Arcade', 'Basketball', 'Simulation', 'Music'),
IN Rating_ip ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'),IN Platform_Name_ip ENUM('N64',      'NES', 'Super Nintendo', 'Gamecube', 'Wii', 'Playstation 1', 'Playstation 2',     'Playstation 3', 'Xbox', 'Xbox 360', 'Sega Genesis', 'Atari 2600', 'Gameboy     Color', 'Gameboy Advance'),IN Completeness_Type_ip ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC',     'BI', 'IC', 'BIC'),     IN Condition_ip ENUM('New', 'Mint', 'Very Good', 'Good',    'Acceptable', 'Poor'),
IN from_Purchase_date_ip DATE,IN to_Purchase_date_ip DATE ,IN     from_Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2), IN to_Purchase_Price_ip DECIMAL(4,2))
Begin
SELECT 
    video_game.Game_Name,
    video_game.Genre,
    video_game.Rating,
    platform.Platform_Name,
     mycollection.Completeness_Type,
      mycollection.`Condition`,
    mycollection.Purchase_Date,
    mycollection.Purchase_Price
        FROM
    video_game
        INNER JOIN
    video_game_platform_mycollection ON video_game.Game_Id =     video_game_platform_mycollection.Game_Id
        INNER JOIN
    platform ON video_game_platform_mycollection.Platform_Id =     platform.Platform_Id
         INNER JOIN
    mycollection ON video_game_platform_mycollection.MyCollection_Id =     mycollection.MyCollection_Id
     where video_game.Game_Name  LIKE CONCAT('%', Game_Name_ip, '%') and       video_game.Genre=Genre_ip and video_game.Rating=Rating_ip
     and platform.Platform_Name=Platform_Name_ip and      mycollection.Completeness_Type=Completeness_Type_ip and     mycollection.`Condition`= Condition_ip
    and mycollection.Purchase_Date between from_Purchase_date_ip and     to_Purchase_date_ip and   mycollection.Purchase_Price >=from_Purchase_Price_ip     and mycollection.Purchase_Price<= to_Purchase_Price_ip;
 END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably check the value of each parameter in the where statement. Here's a start:

```
where 
((Game_Name_ip is null OR len(trim(Game_Name_ip)) > 0) OR video_game.Game_Name  LIKE CONCAT('%', Game_Name_ip, '%')) and
...
```

So basically, you'd be checking to see if the value is null or a string containing only whitespace. If that is false, then that means there is content to search on, so you'd be checking the actual game name value against the specified Game_Name_ip parameter. Repeat this pattern for each value in the WHERE statement.